# Bucketizing Kafka Data with Partitions

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a situation where I’m loading data into Kafka. I would like to process the records in discrete 10m buckets. But bare in mind that the record time stamps come from the producers and so they may not be perfectly in the right order so I can’t simply use the standard Kafka consumer approach since that will result in records outside of my discrete bucket.

Is it possible to use partitions for this? I could look at the timestamp of each record before placing it in the topic, using that to select the appropriate partition. But I don’t know if Kafka supports adhoc named partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They aren't "named" partitions. Sure, you could define a topic with 6 partitions (10 minute "buckets", ignoring hours and days) and a `Partitioner` subclass that computes which partition the record timestamp will go into with a simple math function, however, this is really only useful for ordering and doesn't address that you need to consume from two partitions for every non-exact 10 minute interval. E.g. records at minute 11 (partition 1) would need to consume records with minute 1-9 (partition 0).

Overall, sounds like you want sliding/hopping windowing features of Kafka Streams, not the plain Consumer API. And this will work without writing custom Producer Partitioners with any number of partitions.

Comment: This solution actually does work because the bucket I want to consume is always the complete 10m bucket. I’m other words, I never want to consume 10:31-41. It’s always. 10:30-40.

Comment: Sure, but the consumer doesn't know this; it'll treat `10:30` the same as `11:30`, for example

Comment: In other words, any given partition is only ordered by producer insert events, not the timestamps themselves. If you have producers in different timezones, your hours and days will get mixed together in different orders.

Comment: I’m using UTC timestamps

Comment: Okay, but like I said, Kafka partitions aren't sorted by anything more than the sequential order of when producers send the data. If you have many producers, there's no guarantee you're grouping each instance, individually. Assuming that's what you are trying to do

Comment: Yeah no sorting is necessary. I just need to be able to process time slices as well-defined units.